# Setting "SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR" in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

In Android 8.0 and newer you can have a light navigation bar. In Android Studio you set the UI flag `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR` with the method `setSystemUiVisibility(int)`. Is this feature existing in Xamarin.Android?

Screenshot from Gmail app on Android 8.1.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this in your activity:

```
Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightNavigationBar;
```

... and also ensure that your target framework is set to 8.0 (Oreo)

Comment: There is no member `LightNavigationBar` of `SystemUiFlags`. However thanks for the `Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility =` part I didn't know about that.

Comment: I have the member in my project: [IntDefinition ("Android.Views.View.SystemUiFlagLightNavigationBar", JniField = "android/view/View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR")]
public const SystemUiFlags LightNavigationBar = 16;

Comment: Just made some further testing - it seems that your target framework needs to be Android 8.0 (Oreo), in order for the member to show :) hope it helps

Comment: I have set the flag now thanks to you. But the navbar becomes invisible. Feel free to add the answer here if you have a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382054/7885142

Comment: Sure thing. I will do that then :)