# Setting a light navigation bar makes it invisible

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-navigation-bar

I have set the following to have a light navigation bar:

```
Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightNavigationBar;
```

However, in my app, the navigation bar became invisible:

[image]

Gmail app showing the wanted result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting LightNavigationBar, means that your buttons will fit a light theme (so they will be black, for a light background) - but you might want to change the navigationbar background as well. Here is how to do so in your activity:

```
Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Color.Green);
```

Hope it helps :)